# What version of python is needed for AWS SAM CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to use sam build for a python code, but python doesn't show up as an option when it asks you what runtime you'd like to use. I read on here that AWS SAM CLI only works with Python 3.9, is that still the case?

According to the Python website, Python 3.9 is no longer available for download, so does that mean I won't be able to use AWS SAM CLI, or is there a way around this?

Comment: Python 3.9 is very much available for download from the python.org site, as is pretty much every version going back to 1.1. What makes you think it isn't? Also,  end of support for Python 3.9 is 2025-10, over 2 years away.

Comment: @jarmod When I try to download Python 3.9.16, I get this message: "According to the release calendar specified in PEP 596, Python 3.9 is now in the "security fixes only" stage of its life cycle: the 3.9 branch only accepts security fixes and releases of those are made irregularly in source-only form until October 2025. Python 3.9 isn't receiving regular bug fixes anymore, and binary installers are no longer provided for it. Python 3.9.13 was the last full bugfix release of Python 3.9 with binary installers."

Comment: It does indeed seem that Python.org is now only offering source downloads for Python 3.9. If you want a nicer installer, you can use Anaconda / Miniconda  or Pyenv.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are looking for the Windows version of Python 3.9

Python 3.9.13 was the last full bugfix release of Python 3.9 with binary installers. Download it and install it on your computer.

The installer location is here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3913/

You will not get the latest bug fix, but at least you can run AWS SAM CLI